# How DbCommand.CreateParameter() instantiate an abstract class?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

In ado.net DbParameter is an abstract class and hence can not be instantiated but then how DbCommand.CreateParameter() instantiate the same?

Comment: Why do you believe it instantiates an abstract class?

Comment: Because on hovering over CreateParameter(), the intellisense says "Creates a new instance of a System.Data.Common.DbParameter object."

Comment: @BhupinderSingh That's the *type of the return expression*, not the *type of the instance* returned. eg. an actual `SqlCommand` class (subtype of DbCommand) will return a `SqlParameter` (subtype of SqlDbParameter).

Answer (score 0):

Because `DbCommand` is abstract, a caller will only ever access the overridden and non-abstract `CreateParameter` of a type derived from `DbCommand`.

The documentation is explaining the expected behavior of `CreateParameter` to both callers who are using the `DbCommand` and implementors who are writing a specific override.